# RegEx - Get value from between two strings ignoring white space

Tags: .net, regex

I've got a string that looks a bit like this : `blah Wt       10.35 kg blah`

And I'm using : `(?<=Wt)(.*?)(?=kg)`

To get the value of the weight (between Wt and kg) - but it's also pulling the white space  from either side.

Can anyone tell me please how I can tweak the expression to just give me back the value and not the white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the spaces in the lookarounds:

```
(?<=Wt\s*)(\S+)(?=\s*kg)
```

Since you use the .net framework you can use a variable length lookbehind (which is often forbidden in other regex flavour)

`\s` is the character class for white characters (spaces, tab, newlines)

`\S` means all that is not in `\s`

I used `\S+` instead of `.*?` to avoid a lazy quantifier, and to trim spaces around the target substring.

Comment: Nice improvement, don't forget to add [some explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177757/are-answers-that-just-contain-a-regular-expression-pattern-really-good-answers). Why we could use unfixed length lookbehinds here, the meaning of `\S+` etc :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a group anyways, you may just add a non-capturing group:

`(?<=Wt)(?:\s*)(.*?)(?:\s*)(?=kg)`

`\s*` will match zero or more whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `(?<=Wt)\s+(.*?)\s+(?=kg)`

The \s+ should eat out white spaces and leave just the value.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)